# Error searching multiple models with Sunspot Solr Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

Finally got Sunspot working when searching a single model, but running into some problems when searching multiple.

The error that I'm getting after making a search:

```
Missing template search/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/Indokathan/code/iibfy/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
```

search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :title

 searchable do
   text :title      
  end
end
```

search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

def index
@search = Sunspot.search [Dairy, Drink] do
  fulltext params[:search]
 end
  @results = @search.results
 end  
end
```

searchbar.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, :method => :get do %>
<p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], style:"width:550px; height:30px;" %><br>
    <%= submit_tag "Search!", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg", style: "margin-top:10px" %>
</p>
```

Any help as to why I am getting this error would be more than appreciated. If you need any more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing Single model search, you're rendering the result in same index page of respected controller, for example let's take Article model as in gem document(`articles_controller.rb`).

```
def index
  @search = Article.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      with(:published_at).less_than(Time.zone.now)
    facet(:publish_month)
    with(:publish_month, params[:month]) if params[:month].present?
  end
  @articles = @search.results
end
```

It will render result in same Article index page.

Since, now you've created a common search controller, you will need to create a separate view for this `index` action in `views>search>index.html.erb` and show results in that page or render existing template if that can be used using `render :=> "your_view"`.